# How to display the last inserted id in db using Laravel after creating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Patient Controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
    
        $input = request()->all();
        Patient::create($input);
        dd($input->id);
        // return redirect()->route('medical.create',compact('input'));
       
    }
```

This is my medical.create view

```
{!! Form::model($input, [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'action' => ['MedicalController@store', $input->id]
]) !!}
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    
                        <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('patient_id','Patient no:')}}
                        {{Form::text('patient_id', null, array('class' => 'form-control') )}}
                        </div>

                </div>
                
        </div>
      

             {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I want to get my last inserted id after storing, and display the last id in the next form, but this is the error appear in my screen:

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

This is my Patient table:

[image]

Comment: $patient = Patient::create($input);
        dd($patient ->id);

Comment: but this is the error after creating Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: first print only $patient and see in that id included?

Comment: yes there's no id I changed my code to dd($input)

Comment: array:12 [▼
  "_token" => "BVFdC1JCfL55mYfRSIXzd3nKXF0clzknZrBoXWRC"
  "firstname" => "SAD"
  "middlename" => "SADAAA"
  "lastname" => "SADSA"
  "email" => "SA@GMAIL.COM"
  "contact" => "asdsa"

]

Comment: this is the result of dd($input)

Comment: not print input,print result after create new patient - $result = Patient::create($input);and then print_r($result); or print_r($result->id);

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by saving the `Patient` object in a variable when creating it:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = request()->all();
        $patient = Patient::create($input); // Save it in variable
        dd($patient->id); //Now you can access patient id here
        // return redirect()->route('medical.create',compact('patient')); //Also you can pass it to your view
       
    }
```

Comment: but this is the error after creating Trying to get property 'id' of non-object but the data is saved in database

Comment: You probably didn't change variable in your blade. Use`$patient` now, instead of `$input`: `'action' => ['MedicalController@store', $patient->id]`

Comment: {!! Form::model($patient, [
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'action' => ['MedicalController@store', $patient->id]
]) !!}

Comment: like this? sir @zlatan

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Comment: but in my url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/medical/create?patient=14

Comment: Did you change `compact('input')` to `compact('patient')`? Also, I'm not sure what you're doing in the form above. Are you redirecting to this form after you create a patient or? And why is that ID=14 wrong?

Comment: yes sir  return redirect()->route('medical.create',compact('patient'));

Comment: the id 14 is the last data of my db sir

Comment: So did I manage to provide you a solution? Sorry, I don't quire understand you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use id like Code below with least Changes in your code

```
    $input = request()->all();
    $input = Patient::create($input);
    dd($input->id);
    // return redirect()->route('medical.create',compact('input'));
```

Comment: I think this will give an error, since you are overwriting `$input` variable.

Comment: I don't think like you. $input is just an object. so you can overwrite it as easy as you can

Answer (score 0):

you can retrive id after saving data by mass assignments :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = request()->all();
        $patient = new Patient($input); // fill model with mass assignments
        $patient->save() // save instant
        $id = $patient->id; //retrive id
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use compact while redirecting. Try this:

Patient Controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
    
        $input = request()->all();
        $patient = Patient::create($input);
        $patient = DB::table('patients')->get()->last();
        return redirect()->route('medical.create')->with('patient_id', $patient->id);
       
    }
```

This is my medical.create view

```
{!! Form::model($input, [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'action' => ['MedicalController@store', session('patient_id')]
]) !!}
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    
                        <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('patient_id','Patient no:')}}
                        {{Form::text('patient_id', null, array('class' => 'form-control') )}}
                        </div>

                </div>
                
        </div>
      

             {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Hi Sir Nurbek, Thank you for your answer but the error is $patient is undefined

Comment: did it create something in database

Comment: yes, sir, it created my only problem is to display the last id in my form

Comment: Hi sir if I dd($patient->id) the id, for example, the result is 33 so this is correct. The problem is I want to pass this 33 id to my medical.create view in my form is it possible ?

Comment: you can pass it like return redirect('/something')->with('patient_id', 33);   and in your create you can take it like {{ session('patient_id') }} that is it